# Nativescript Gestures not working on android views with ScrollViews

Tags: android, scrollview, nativescript, gesture, absolutelayout

Hello I have a `AbsoluteLayout` with a `(pan)="onPan($event)"` gesture on it.

I noticed if I have a `ScrollView` on the page and you try to pan from the scroll view the `onPan` event is no longer triggered. This only happens on android, it works perfectly on IOS.

```
  <AbsoluteLayout width="100%" (pan)="onPan($event)">
    <StackLayout left="{{tabs.store.left}}" height="100%" width="100%">
        <store></store>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout left="{{tabs.profile.left}}" height="100%" width="100%" class="StaticBg">
      <profile></profile>
    </StackLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

My `store` component has a `ScrollView` and you can't pan from that page on android.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By nature Android's ScrollView operates by intercepting it's touch events. So you might have to add the pan event to ScrollView / it's child component.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I really hoped I would find a simple fix to a massive issue. Thanks I found your answer! Have a good day!

Comment: What if you have 2 containers inside the `<ScrollView>` that need to handle gestures? Ex: 2 image carousels inside one `<ScrollView>`?  Sample/example would be much appreciated.